# How to alter data being displayed using an SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running an SQL query daily to generate a report which will be sent out in a batch file.  When I run the query, under the ActionID Column there are two possible values: 21 and 33.  Since these values dont mean anything to the user I want to convert all the entries that are 21 to a string that says: Moved succesfully to:.  For all the entries that are 33 I want to convert them into a string that said Moving failed.  For both of these strings, I want it under a new column named Comments instead of ActionID.  I have the following code but it is giving me some errors.  Can anyone make any alterations to my code for this to run successfully?  That would be greatly appreciated.

```
   SELECT  ItemId AS [Item ID],
   CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS DATE) 'Date',
   LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS TIME),8) 'Time',
  [Object] AS [Media],
  SourceSite AS [Source Site], where ActionID = '21' to
  'Was successfully moved to' AS [Comments] AND where ActionID ='33' 'Was  unsuccessful'  AS [Comments],
  DestSite AS [Destination Site]
  FROM (  SELECT  ItemId,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
  [Object],
  SourceSite,
  DestSite,
        UserCode
  FROM JnlMediumMove
  WHERE CAST(substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 0, 5) + '-' +
  substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 5, 2) + '-' +
  substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 7, 2) AS DATETIME) =
  CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))) A --Converting to date again to remove     the time part
  WHERE UserCode = 'Automation'
  ORDER BY [Date] DESC;
```

Comment: Why not add a table that maps `ActionId|Description`, `JOIN` to it and select its `Description` instead of `ActionID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a CASE statement, basic format:

```
CASE WHEN criteria1 THEN result1
     WHEN criteria2 THEN result2
     ELSE default result
END
```

In your query:

```
   SELECT  ItemId AS [Item ID],
   CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS DATE) 'Date',
   LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS TIME),8) 'Time',
  [Object] AS [Media],
  SourceSite AS [Source Site], 
  CASE WHEN  ActionID = '21' THEN 'Was successfully moved to' 
       WHEN  ActionID ='33' THEN 'Was  unsuccessful'
       ELSE '' --Optional ELSE
  END  AS [Comments],
  DestSite AS [Destination Site]
  FROM (  SELECT  ItemId,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
  [Object],
  SourceSite,
  DestSite,
  ActionID,
        UserCode
  FROM JnlMediumMove
  WHERE CAST(substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 0, 5) + '-' +
  substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 5, 2) + '-' +
  substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 7, 2) AS DATETIME) =
  CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))) A --Converting to date again to remove     the time part
  WHERE UserCode = 'Automation'
  ORDER BY [Date] DESC;
```

Edit: Assuming you forgot to add ActionID to your subquery.

Comment: It says:Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'ActionId'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'ActionId'.

Comment: Oh, you don't have ActionID in your select list. Where does it come from? Your question made it sound like you already had a query selecting ActionID.

Comment: It's in the table, I just dont want that column to appear in the display.  If I add it to the select list, will it work?

Comment: Or I want Comments Column to replace Action ID column that would be fine too.

Comment: Yeah, I added it to the subquery select list, it needs to be available for the CASE statement by being selected in the subquery, but you don't have to return it, see updated answer.